# dynamic destination on exit block

Tags: simulation, anylogic

i need to forward an agent to a specific service depending on a cycle written in a database; in the [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ALHh.png), i have written the following code:

```
serviceTo = selectFrom(ciclo)
.where(ciclo.sequenza.eq(agent.sequenza))
.where(ciclo.sku.eq(agent.SKU))
.uniqueResult(ciclo.service);
```

serviceTo.take(agent)

the problem is that: "serviceTo" is a string and the method take is not working with that. how can i use the "serviceTo" variable in order to deliver the agent to the right enter?

Comment: what values you have in the database?  "service1", "service2", "service3" and "service4"?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to parse your value, eg. convert your string *serviceTo*, that you retrieve from the database to a Java/AnyLogic object of type *Enter*.

In order to do so, create a Collection *allMyEntersCollecton* of type Enter and add all your Enter-objects that you want to be able to parse. You can also do this by selecting all your Enter blocks, right click, and use *create Collection*.
Create a parsing function *parseEnter* that returns a result of type *Others/Enter* and takes an input parameter *serviceTo* of type String:

```java
for(int i=0;i<allMyEntersCollection.size();i++){
    if(allMyEntersCollection.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(serviceTo)){
        return allMyEntersCollection.get(i);
    }
}

//nothing found, will probably cause a NullPointerException later:
return null;
```

Now all you have to do is to run this function *parseEnter* with your parameters:

```java
 Enter serviceToObject = parseEnter(serviceTo);
```

Of course the parsing only works if the String really contains exactly the name of any of the Enter objects in your Collection.

Use the resulting Enter-object:

```java
 serviceToObject.take(myExampleAgent);
```

[image: Screenshot of parsing function]